# Having trouble with the messagebox.show

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm having trouble with the messagebox.show. I want the answer and this line "would you like to try another temp conversion?" to appear on a message box with yesno buttons.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim intFah As Windows.Forms.DialogResult

    Private Sub BtnFah_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnFah.Click
        Try
            Dim intFah As Integer

            intFah = CInt(TxtBoxTemp.Text)
            intFah = (intFah * 9) / 5 - 32
            MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't build for me - it's probably because in your MessageBox.Show:

```
MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

You aren't passing the right number of [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx). As per the link, it needs the text, a caption (title) and then the button options

If I change it to:

```
MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "A Caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

Then it builds and when I run the app I can get the answer appearing in one line and the text on a second line as per what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. Now I just have to make sure the buttons on the message box work.